# 2 operating systems on a partitioned not loading up

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-xp

I have 2 operating systems on a hard drive (old XP and W7), both are unable to start, this happened out of the blue. I get blue error screen saying about changes in hardware or software, but there has not been no changes.

In W7 Startup Repair is saying that it cannot repair computer automatically.

What I have done: run chkdsk, no errors; tried manually fixmbr and fixboot (bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot); used restore point; tried last known good configuration with no changes. I tried running sfc, but this one gives me an error that "a repair is pending and computer needs to be reboot". But I cannot reboot it, it wont load up!

All I can do is access cmd prompt from Repair Computer menu.

Is this a hardware or software failure? It seems to be software.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: It's time to upgrade. Get a new computer and recover your data.

Comment: Sounds like you've done all that really can be done. Time to boot to another drive and get what you can off of it. It may continue to work as a data drive for awhile but I wouldn't trust it. Also, it may work fine to boot non Windows OS if it's having errors reporting HWID as long as those OS don't require it.